# adding a class to EditorFor - razor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

(The editor is for a DateTime property called "ADate"

I am trying this but it does not work.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADate, new { cssClass = "date" } )
```

So I tried this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ADate, new { @class = "date" })
```

but it outputs type = text.. ofcourse it does.

So I tried a template... I added a folder in shared:

```
Shared/EditorTemplates
```

and then I created a .cshtml partial view called **Date.cshtml**

Now what on earth do I put inside it :O...

I have tried to understand lots of posts and stack overflow entries but it's not sinking in.

The goal is to attach a **datepicker** to the class **".date"** across the entire app where **".date"** class is used... The TextBoxFor works with my adding class part... but as I said, the type changes from date to text :(

Comment: Have you read this: http://www.nickharris.net/2010/08/asp-net-mvc-editor-template-for-jquery-datepicker/ ?

Comment: @FilipEkberg - I need a bit more help buddy.. totally don't get it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so this is what you can do:

In your `EditorTemplates` folder create a template called `DateTime.cshml` (the name will resolve automatically if you use it for dates, otherwise you have to specify it when using it).
Then in it:

```
@model System.DateTime

@Html.TextBox(
   string.Empty, 
   Model.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
   new { @class="datepicker", @type = "date"})
```

Using the last parameter you can specify any html attribute (class, data, type etc.).

Then you use it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ADate)
```

In case you chose to name your template with a different name you can specify it by invoking another overload:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ADate, "MyOtherAwesomeTemplate")
```

Comment: For some reason the template is not being called when the name is "DateTime.cshtml", instead I have to explicitly call it with the overloaded string? any ideas? My property is definetly DateTime type

Comment: @JamesT Hey James, not sure what the issue might be. Are you sure you don't have multiple templates ? Also, is your template located in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/` ? Could you perhaps show how you're using it (and how you've defined it) ? I've tried testing it here with every scenario I can think of and I couldn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 2):

The EditorFor html helper does not render a date picker for your DateTime attributes (if that's what you want to do). The default EditorFor for DateTime is a text input. If you want to use a date picker, you'll have to use jQuery DatePicker (or any other third party date picker).

Also, the EditorFor helper does not have a parameter for html attributes. If you want to assign a class, you'll have to use TextBoxFor.

In your main View, use the EditorFor like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADate)
```

Then, in your Editor Template (Date.cshtml), you'll have:

```
@model System.DateTime

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".date").datepicker();
    });
</script>

@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("d"), new { @class = "date" })
```

You can download the jQuery UI from here: [Download jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

And, you can learn more about the jQuery DatePicker here: [jQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ADate)

<style type="text/css">

#ADate
{
 @* your css properties goes here *@
}
</style>
```

this works fine for MVC3 Razor